# Auto Login html for live.com account

Tags: javascript, html, outlook

Good Evening Everyone. I need some help with an auto login procedure.

Specific Question = How can I get initiate a 2nd form action within the same html page? I also need to create a 5 second delay so the 1st action can complete

The Result I'm looking for = I want to double click on saved .html file and then get automatically logged into my email

The Website =
HTML Code:
https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1489346474&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fauthRedirect%3dtrue%26nlp%3d1&id=292841&CBCXT=out&fl=wld&cobrandid=90015

How did I get this URL? = msn.com>clicked on outlook>clicked on sign in

The problem =
I have created a javascript function within a saved html page and I can get past the login in page. The issue is that I cannot get my password to be correctly placed in the password field and the submit button to work. For my live.com account it is a 2 page authentication. The first page is where you place your username and click next and then the 2 page is where you enter your password and click sign in.

What I have tried =

- (1)Because there is a placeholder text, I've tried a POST method, but
  I can't get it to work. POST would be best, but I can't figure it
  out.
- (2) I've tried get element by id and that does not work because
  my password is just written on top of the placeholder text and does
  not get replaced
- (3) CURRENT STATE. What I have written now is 2 form
  actions. The 1st form action (logonForm) enters my username and the
  2nd form action (passForm) is supposed to enter my password and then
  log me in. Is 2 form actions the best way to accomplish this?

WHAT  I HAVE SO FAR =

```
<html>
  <body style="display: none">
    <form action="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1485483982&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1&id=292841&CBCXT=out&fl=wld&cobrandid=90015" method="POST" name="logonForm" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
id="loginForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="destination" value="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1485483982&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1&id=292841&CBCXT=out&fl=wld&cobrandid=90015">
      <input type="hidden" name="username"  value="this is my username@live.com" >
      <input type="hidden" name="passwd"  value="this is my password">
      <input type="hidden" name="flags" value="4">
      <input type="hidden" name="forcedownlevel" value="0">
      <input type="radio"  name="trusted" value="4" class="rdo" checked>
      <input type="hidden" name="isUtf8"  value="1">
    </form>


    <form action="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1485483982&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1&id=292841&CBCXT=out&fl=wld&cobrandid=90015" method="POST" name="passForm" ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
id="passwordForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="destination" value="https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1485483982&rver=6.7.6640.0&wp=MBI_SSL&wreply=https%3a%2f%2foutlook.live.com%2fowa%2f%3fnlp%3d1&id=292841&CBCXT=out&fl=wld&cobrandid=90015">
      <input type="hidden" name="username"  value="This is my username@live.com" >
      <input type="hidden" name="passwd"  value="this is my password">
      <input type="hidden" name="flags" value="4">
      <input type="hidden" name="forcedownlevel" value="0">
      <input type="radio"  name="trusted" value="4" class="rdo" checked>
      <input type="hidden" name="isUtf8"  value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="data-bind" value="this is my password">
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.forms["logonForm"].submit();
      document.forms["passForm"].submit();
    </script>


  </body>

</html>
```

I am a new student to java and I'm ambitious about coding, developing, and learning.  I just can't seem to get this figured out. I'm sure my html/java looks like a jumbled mess but that's because I've been trying all types of things to see if anything would work and I got excited when i was able to get past the login page.

I do apologize for the long post, I just wanted to get as much info as I have out. I'm trying to be as specific as I can be. This is my first post in stack overflow and I couldn't be more excited to be part of this community.

Thanks in advance for your help!
TechStudent01

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.

Once a `<form>` is sent (either as `GET` or `POST`), which is a synchronous action, your script basically stops executing, and unless the targeted webpage fails to load (and the browser doesn't display an error page, which can happen with severe network issues), `.submit()` is a no-return function : if it executed properly, you're not on the same page any more.

Letting you run scripts from a webpage onto a newly loaded other would be the open door to loads of security issues, so this, by design, is not allowed. As such, you can't get your password to be typed in automatically into the log-in form.

In addition, Microsoft account forms are subject to [CSRF verification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), preventing you from logging in from a page not sent by Microsoft, i.e. your HTML file.

Also, what you are trying to achieve is exactly the purpose of password managers that provide some sort of browser integration.